# OS dependencies and compatibility of python-pptx module

Tags: python, ubuntu, powerpoint, ubuntu-18.04, python-pptx

I'm running Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.06. I wanted to know about python-pptx module's OS dependencies rather than Python dependency as I need to launch the functionality on a server after developing a model on either Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04. I looked into the documentation of the module but the information needed is not provided. Does the module update fit my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

yes, python-pptx will work on Ubuntu